# Python : Speed up Reverse DNS lookup

Tags: python, dns, reverse, reverse-dns

I am planning to run Reverse DNS on 47 Million ips. Here is my code

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
    with open ('./ip_ptr_new.txt','a') as w:

        for l in f:

            la = l.rstrip('\n')
            ip,countdomain = la.split('|')
            ips.append(ip)

           try:
                ais = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
                print ("%s|%s|%s" % (ip,ais[0],countdomain), file = w)    
           except:
                print ("%s|%s|%s" % (ip,"None",countdomain), file = w)
```

Currently it is very slow. Does anybody have any suggestions for speed it up?

Comment: Run multiple threads/processes

Comment: @matino my machine has two cpu only. and with python multiprocessing module two would not speed it up that much. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Just because you have 2 CPUs doesn't mean you can only run 2 processes at once. Try running with more - it's unlikely that this code is CPU-bound.

Comment: Well you could use 2 processes each spawning multiple threads, each thread 1) reads only part of the file 2) for that part is looking up the host

Comment: @matino Thanks. It would be really helpful to me if you can write the answer separately .

Answer (score 1):

Try using a multiprocessing module. I have timed the performance for about 8000 ips and I got this:

```
#dns.py
real    0m2.864s
user    0m0.788s
sys     0m1.216s


#slowdns.py
real    0m17.841s
user    0m0.712s
sys     0m0.772s


# dns.py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import socket
def dns_lookup(ip):
    ip, countdomain = ip
    try:
        ais = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
        print ("%s|%s|%s" % (ip,ais[0],countdomain))
    except:
        print ("%s|%s|%s" % (ip,"None",countdomain))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = "input.txt"
    ips = []
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        with open ('./ip_ptr_new.txt','a') as w:
            for l in f:
                la = l.rstrip('\n')
                ip,countdomain = la.split('|')
                ips.append((ip, countdomain))
    p = Pool(5)
    p.map(dns_lookup, ips)





#slowdns.py
import socket
from multiprocessing import Pool

filename = "input.txt"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ips = []
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        with open ('./ip_ptr_new.txt','a') as w:
            for l in f:
               la = l.rstrip('\n')
               ip,countdomain = la.split('|')
               ips.append(ip)
               try:
                    ais = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
                    print ("%s|%s|%s" % (ip,ais[0],countdomain), file = w)
               except:
                    print ("%s|%s|%s" % (ip,"None",countdomain), file = w)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that number of ips are a lot and to put them into a list it takes almost 90% of the memory. Is there a way to read line by line and pass it to multiprocessing module/.?

Comment: Sorry I missed that requirement. In that case you cannot use the list, instead you will have to use a queue. Reading from large files would still be ok since python uses generators and not lists.  Please check this thread out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677287/multiprocessing-with-large-data

Comment: hmm Thanks. But I still do not know how to make use of the queue in this case

Comment: OK, I will see if  I'll be able to post an edit some time today with  the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

One solution here is to use the nslookup shell commande with the option timeout. Possibly the host command... 
    An example not perfect but useful!

```
def sh_dns(ip,dns):
   a=subprocess.Popen(['timeout','0.2','nslookup','-norec',ip,dns],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   sortie=a.stdout.read()
   tab=str(sortie).split('=')
   if(len(tab)>1):
     return tab[len(tab)-1].strip(' \\n\'')
   else:
     return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

We recently had to deal with this problem also.
Running on multiple processes didn't provide a good enough solution.
It could take several days to process few millions of IPs from a strong AWS machine.
What worked well is using [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/), it took around half an hour on 10 machines cluster.
You cannot scale too much with one machine (and usually one network interface) as it's a network intensive task. Using Map Reduce with multiple machines certainly did the work.