# Evaluating a function parallely using itertools product

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have to evaluate a function (let's call it my_func()) that takes 8 parameters as input and returns a scalar upon different matrix computations. Since I don't have any constrains on my_func(), I have no choice but to brute force all possibilities which amounts to 8^8 = 16777216. I started off using itertools's product functions and passed the generated sequences to the my_func() sequentially. Kindly take a look at the sample of my code below,

**So far.....**

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

def my_func(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h): #Function that I have to evaluate
    #do some matrix computations and return some scalar q# 
    return q

def Evaluate():
    Range = [x for x in np.arange(0,3.60,0.5)] # A list that contains 8 elements
    it = itertools.product(Range, repeat=8) #Generate all possiblities
    Max = 0
    for i in it:
        Sum = my_func(*i)
        if Sum > Max:
            Max = present
    return Max

Result = Evaluate() #Output
```

**Pitfalls...**

Unfortunately, executing the above code sequentially takes ages to produce the output. This is because my_func is quite heavy. I have no choice but to somehow parallelize this code so that I can take advantage of multiple processors available to run my code.

**Questions:**

Since itertools.product is a generator I cannot parallelize this to evaluate my_func() simultaneously for different sets of parameters. 
Is there any way I can parallelize the code? if no is the asnswer, should I abondon the idea of using itertools and try someting else?

Kindly help me find a solution.

Thanks for suggesting any ideas.

Cheers!!

Comment: is the function that returns the scalar symmetric under index permutations? if I do f(1,0,0...,0) does it return the same as f(0,0,...,1)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the scalar is not symmetric under permutations, I wish it would have been. The function returns different values for different sets of arguments.

Comment: Your code appears to be missing a line, eg `for i in it:`. BTW, `my_func(*i)` is more compact than your call. Also consider `Range = [i/2 for i in range(8)]`; make that `i/2.` if your on Python 2 and not using `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: @PM 2Ring thanks for the suggestions.  I have added that missing line to my code. cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parallelize a generator ! You can use the `multiprocessing` library, which offers the `Pool` class which does exactly what you want. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) you can get more ample documentation, but essentially, what you want to do is :

```
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
  pool.map(my_func, itertools.product(Range, repeat=8))
```

You should look into the alternatives to `pool.map` to find the one which suits you most.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I noticed that by mapping  itertools.product(Range, repeat=8) to my_func, soon runs out of memory. I think all the 8^8 possibilities are generated, stored  and  then passed as chunks to different processors. Any workarounds?

Comment: You may want to look into the answers given here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318936/python-multiprocessing-pool-lazy-iteration and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677287/multiprocessing-with-large-data

Answer (score 3):

The number of cores you'll use is probably much smaller than  *8<sup>8</sup>* .

This leads to the following parallallelization scheme. Call [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) on

```
itertools.product(<all-combinations-of-first-2-or-3-parameters>)
```

Within each process, perform the parallellization on the remaining parameters, and return only a single result - the best tuple of parameters found.

This will be much more efficient anyway than passing each of the *8<sup>8</sup>* combinations. There's an overhead to these things.

**Example**

Say you decide to map over the first three parameters. Then your `product` is a sequence of triplets: `..., (1, 3, 2), ...`. You use something like `multiprocessing.Pool.map` on each such triplet, so let's consider it from the point of view of the function:

```
def find_best_for_triplet(xyz):
    x, y, z = xyz[0], xyz[1], xyz[2]

    for ... in itertools.product(<all-combinations-of-last-5-parameters>)
        # Here you have all 8 of your parameters: x, y, z, and the last 5

    return xyz + (last-five-parameters) of the min
```

---

On a separate matter - in practice, the [Nelder Mead method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) works well on optimizing high-dimensional problems, and is much cheaper than brute force. You might wish to give an implementation of it a try.

Comment: Hello Dr. Tavory, Thanks for the help. Certainly passing 8^8 combinations  is a lot of overhead, in fact number of parameters will even go up to 10, then I have to brute-force 10^10 which is awful lot.  I read your answer several times but couldn't get my head around it. Are you suggesting to evaluate the function with only a subset of parameters (keeping the rest const) in a single process? Could you kindly explain a bit further in your answer?

Comment: @Prdeep_nitro I've added a clarification/explanation. Let me know if you need something further.