# How to combine many numpy arrays efficiently?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having difficulty trying to load 18k of training data for training with tensorflow. The files are npy files named as such: 0.npy, 1.npy...18000.npy.

I was looking around the web and came up with a simple code to first read the files in the correct sequence and trying to concatenate the training data together but it takes forever..

```py
import numpy as np
import glob
import re
import tensorflow as tf

print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.__version__))

files = glob.glob('D:/project/train/*.npy')
files.sort(key=lambda var:[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in 
           re.findall(r'[^0-9]|[0-9]+', var)])
# print(files)

final_dataset = []
i = 0
for file in files:    
    dataset = np.load(file, mmap_mode='r')
    print(i)
    #print("Size of dataset: {} ".format(dataset.shape))
    if (i==0):
      final_dataset = dataset
    else: 
      final_dataset = np.concatenate((final_dataset, dataset), axis = 0)
    i = i + 1

print("Size of final_dataset: {} ".format(final_dataset.shape))
np.save('combined_train.npy', final_dataset)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Combining' arrays in any way involves (1), creating an array with the two arrays' total size; (2), copying their contents into the array. If you do this each time you load in an array, it repeats 18000 times - with time per iteration *growing* for each iteration (due to larger `final_dataset`).

A simple workaround is to *append* the arrays to a list - and then combine them all *once* at the end:

```py
dataset = []
for file in files:
    data = np.load(file, mmap_mode='r')
    dataset.append(data)

final_dataset = np.concatenate(dataset, axis=0)
```

But *beware*: be sure `final_dataset` can actually fit in your RAM, else the program will crash. You can find out via `ram_required = size_per_file * number_of_files`. Relevant [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133885/fastest-way-to-grow-a-numpy-numeric-array). (To speed things up even further, you can look into [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677287/multiprocessing-with-large-data) - but not simple to get working)